# UI to managing specific applicationhost.config

Tags: iis-7, configuration-management, iis

I'm doing some work with IIS Express and it has it's own `applicationhost.config`.

Is there any UI that I could use to manage that config file without editing the XML directly? I downloaded [IIS Manager for Remote Administration](http://www.iis.net/download/iismanager) but that still connect to the default `applicationhost.config` of the machine.

Answer (score 1):

No, IIS Express is meant to be an *Express* version, thus the name, and there are no GUI plugins available for the applicationHost.config

However, if you are not sure of what the different sections in the applicationHost.config actually controls, have a look at the Config Reference at http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference

Another approach, although somewhat exhausting, would be to make the configuration changes to your "regular" IIS installation with the Remote Administration tool, check out the differences it produces in the applicationHost.config, and apply those to your IIS Express configuration.

PS. do yourself a favor and use a text editor with XML syntax highlighting, it makes it a lot easier to spot any typos with regards to correct syntax.